# ReferenceError: spyOn is not defined Angularjs/Karma/Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am using AngularJS with karma using the Jasmine framework. I have several other tests running and working. My problem is when I am trying to run this:

```
spyOn(window, 'confirm').and.returnValue(true);
```

I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: spyOn is not defined
```

Here is my config:

```
module.exports = function() {
  return {
    basePath: '../',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    reporters: ['progress'],
    browsers: ['Chrome_without_security'],
    autoWatch: true,
    // these are default values anyway
    singleRun: false,
    colors: true,
    plugins : [
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-ng-scenario'
            ],
    customLaunchers: {
      Chrome_without_security: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--disable-web-security']
      }
    },
    files : [
      'static/js/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'static/js/app.js',
      'static/js/controllers.js'
    ]
  }
};

var sharedConfig = require('./karma-shared.conf');

module.exports = function(config) {
  var conf = sharedConfig();

  conf.files = conf.files.concat([
    //test files
    './tests/e2e/account/sign-up.js',
    './tests/e2e/account/sign-in.js',
    './tests/e2e/organization/*.js',
    //'./tests/e2e/**/*.js',
    './tests/e2e/account/sign-out.js'
  ]);

  conf.proxies = {
    '/': 'http://localhost/'
  };

  conf.urlRoot = '/__karma__/';

  conf.frameworks = ['ng-scenario'];

  config.set(conf);
};
```

The config consists of a shared and specific config for e2e tests.

I have everything else work and Jasmine is specified as the framework in my Karma config. Any ideas?

Comment: ng-scenario syntax is similar to Jasmine's but not identical. Are you sure that Jasmine is actually loaded? Are you trying to spyOn in a unit test or an integration test?

Comment: This is a old question. I faced similar issue. I had to use jest.spyOn to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside your test script:

```
describe('testing spy',function(){
  var window_confirmSpy;

  beforeEach(function(){
    window_confirmSpy = spyOn(window, 'confirm').and.callThrough();
  });

  it('testing windows confirm method',function(){
    window.confirm();

    expect(window_confirmSpy).tohaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('testing windows confirm method with parameter',function(){
    window.confirm('parameter');

    expect(window_confirmSpy).tohaveBeenCalledWith('parameter');
  });
});
```

Above code snippet will ensure that `window.confirm()` is called or not.